# Posting results from Android wifi scan to SQL/MySQL database using JSON

Tags: android, mysql, sql, json, wifi

How can I send the results of my wifi scan to SQL/MySQL database i have created to populate values SSID, BSSID and RSSI using JSON? I have so far been able to output these results to a list (see below code).

```
package com.example.wifiscanner8;

import java.util.List;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textStatus;
    TextView textState;
    WifiManager mainWifi;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     //enable wifi on application start

            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getBaseContext()
                     .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
             wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

       textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
       mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
       registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
       mainWifi.startScan();
       //mainText.setText("Starting Scan...");
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        mainWifi.startScan();
        //mainText.setText("Starting Scan");
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    // Upon pressing back button to exit app, wireless function set to disable
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getBaseContext()
                  .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    this.finish();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }

    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
                handleScanResultsAvailable();
            }
        }

        private void handleScanResultsAvailable() {
            List<ScanResult> results = mainWifi.getScanResults();
            int size = results.size();
            //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
                ScanResult scanresult = mainWifi.getScanResults().get(i);
                String bssid = scanresult.BSSID;
                String ssid = scanresult.SSID;
                int rssi = scanresult.level;
                String rssiString = String.valueOf(rssi);
                textStatus.append(bssid + "," + ssid + "," + rssiString);
                textStatus.append("\n");
            }


                // getting JSON Object
                // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                //JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_wifi_scan_result,
                       // "POST", reading);

                // check log cat from response
               // Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());




            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you communicating to the DB via your Android app? Or do you have some kind of server in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear in that it doesn't specify where the db resides like Stu Whyte pointed out.
If you are using the native sqlite db on the device then you need a SQLHelper, read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).

If instead your database resides on a server you need to serialize your results in some middleware format like JSON or XML and transfer data to a web server, which will manage the database connection . You can use the org.apache.http library natively included which will allow you to post/put data to a web service like a normal web form.
Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).

Comment: Sorry both, The database will be residing on a server. I am currenlty using http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ as reference to posting results of wifi scan into data tables. ultimately, i want to store the data and cross reference it with existing data to enable me to track location.